# Change size of image in Blogdown about.md file inserted via Insert image option

Tags: r-markdown, blogdown

I am trying to change the size of a headshot in my Blogdown about.md file. The theme is Hugo-lithium.

I have inserted my image into the about.md file using the 'Insert Image' option in 'Addins'. The size of the picture that appears in the viewer is giant. The code generated looks as follows:

```
---
date: "2020-07-22T21:48:51-07:00"
title: About
---

![](/./about_files/Monika_headshot.png)

I am passionate about empowering all individuals who care about the empirical underpinnings of policy, with direct access to data.
```

When I try to preview I get the following error even though the image is in the indicated file.

```
pandoc: /./about_files/Monika_headshot.png: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted
```

I have tried to change the size the markdown way and when I do so the image disappears entirely:

```
![](/./about_files/Monika_headshot.png =250x250)
```

or

```
![](/./about_files/Monika_headshot.png | width=100))
```

Neither of these have worked. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with curly braces:

```
![](/./about_files/Monika_headshot.png){width=250px}
```

Comment: This did not work, even though the file is in the specified location

Comment: Let me understand: The picture shows in  the preview or not? Meaning, if you do Serve Site

Comment: Sorry - meant to say, the image is still huge

Comment: @monkeyshines When you said "When I try to preview I get the following error", how did you preview the site? The recommended way is "Serve Site": https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html

Comment: When I have run serve_site() with blogdown now the image is large and underneath the image is the text: {width=250px}. The size command is not working

Answer (score 3):

I deleted copied and pasted the contents from the Blogdown about.md file into a new file about.Rmd, which was in the same folder in the about.md file. The image in the .Rmd file rendered as expected using the above solution

```
![](/./about_files/Monika_headshot.png){width=250px}
```